# Как сделать чтобы консольная программа на Qt сама отработала и завершилась?

Tags: qt, qt5

Пробовал по разному зависает в консоли.

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QCoreApplication a(argc, argv);
    qDebug() <<"Zapusk";
    for(int i=0; i<100; i++) {
        qDebug() <<"Rabotaem";
    }
    // если раскоментировать все равно не работает
   // a.quit();
    return a.exec();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

`a.exec()` запускает цикл событий (event loop), поэтому приложение и не завершается, а ожидает выхода из этого цикла.

Если цикл событий не нужен, то просто возвращайте результат работы:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QCoreApplication a(argc, argv);
    qDebug() <<"Zapusk";
    for(int i=0; i<100; i++) {
        qDebug() <<"Rabotaem";
    }
    a.exit();
    return 0; // Можно ничего не возвращать
}
```

Comment: Я бы сказал, если цикл событий не нужен, то и QCoreApplication не особо нужен

Answer (score 0):

Если убрать всё лишнее то это будет уже консольная программа без Qt.
Почему бы не сделать как в руководстве написано? с задачами.

```
class task : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit task(QCoreApplication* parent) : QObject(parent)
    {
        QObject::connect(this, &task::on_run, this, &task::run, Qt::QueuedConnection);
        QObject::connect(this, &task::finished, parent, &QCoreApplication::quit);
    }
Q_SIGNALS:
    void finished();

    void on_run();
private Q_SLOTS :
    void run()
    {
        // TODO 

        emit finished();
    }
private:
    ~task()
    {

    }
};
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    if (!SetConsoleOutputCP(1251)) return 1;

    QCoreApplication application(argc, argv);
    task *device = new task(&application);


    emit device->on_run();
    return application.exec();
}
```